# Efficient way to find a certain object in multiple ArrayLists in Java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is there a way to find a specific object in a group of ArrayLists such that I first want to find that specific object, then figure out which ArrayList it is in? If there are multiple ways to do this, what is the most efficient way to do this?

EDIT: For some context

```
public class Player {

    private int lifePoints;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;
    private ArrayList<Card> graveyard;
    private Monster[] monsterZones;
    private Card[] spellTrapZones;
    private Context context;

    public Player(Context c) {
        lifePoints = 8000;
        monsterZones = new Monster[5];
        spellTrapZones = new Card[5];
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        graveyard = new ArrayList<Card>();
        context = c;
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        deck = FileHandler.loadFromFile("test.deck", context);
    }    

    public void draw() {
        hand.add(deck.remove(0));
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    public void sendToGraveyard(Monster monster) {
        graveyard.add(monster);
        //I want to add code that would use the Monster parameter to find that specific Monster and remove it from the ArrayList it is in 
    }
```

}

Comment: For a small number of lists and a small number of elements in each (for an operation done relatively infrequently), just check them all - it will be O(n*m). For significantly larger values you won't want to use lists (by themselves) like this. Adding additional context/details may be useful.

Comment: the method contains is not sufficient ?

Comment: Alternatively you could use a `Set`, such as `HashSet`. With a proper hashCode `.contains` lookup would then be O(1)

Comment: I've added code just for a little context of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make my example as if the Object's name is Car.

Make a Tuple by using your preferred library or create a Object containing a tuple Car, List (your array). Name it CarTuple.

Try a HashMap like `HashMap<String, CarTuple>()`

Where the String is the reference of the object (like an id). Then the real object and it's array list can be found in O(1).

Comment: `HashMap<String, List<List<...>,Object>>` I am pretty sure that is not valid.

Comment: The 'Object' is the the object contain in is array list (ex. Car) The HashMap would then be HashMap<String, List<List<...>, Car>>()

Comment: A `Map<K,V>` still has only two parameters, it'd make sense to state that instead of `...` instead

Comment: My bad I made a mistake, please see the edited comment.

Comment: Just so I'm on the same page, I would store the Object and the ArrayList with the object inside the Tuple?

Comment: You can use a tuple or create your class like: public class CarTuple { private Car car; private List<Car> dealerCars; } With the setters and the getters.